# how to do pretty url in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-route

i am wondering how can i do pretty urls with zend framework?

some background:

my url right now is: `www.website.com/profile/43`

the database structure is:

```
id   userid    name
1    43        John
..   ...       ...
```

and my router is:

```
$router->addRoute('getUserid',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                    '/profile/:id',
                    array(
                            'module' => 'profile',
                            'controller' => 'social',
                            'action' => 'index'

                    )
            )
    );
```

obviously i would like the url to be: `www.website.com/profile/John`

from what research i mane it looks like i can do a lot of things with the router, add regexp, etc, but nothing on how to replace the `id` like in my case.

I need to do a query to find out the name and i was thinking to do it in the predispatch and use the result as a default variable, but i don't know the `id` since the `$front->getRequest()->getParams()` is not available :

```
$name = // do query to find out the name;

$router->addRoute('getUserid',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                    '/profile/:id',
                    array(
                            'id' => $name,
                            'module' => 'profile',
                            'controller' => 'social',
                            'action' => 'index'

                    )
            )
    );
```

maybe im going at this from the wrong point. Any ideas?

thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with your current implementation? Why do you want to change it?

Comment: i need the id to be `john` instead of '43'

Comment: do that in your controller. It is not a router job.

Comment: perform a query to find a name by id

Comment: and how do i add it to the url? i don't want to do a LIKE = 'John'.

Comment: Don't you think there is the possibility of having more than one `John`?  You should keep the `id` in the URL as the identifier, and just add the name for prettiness.  Look at how SO does URL's for questions, they include the ID and add the question title slug to the URL, but that is simply for SEO and serves no purpose as far as retrieving the data.  Therefore, make your URL something like `site.com/profile/43/John-Smith`

Comment: i see, maybe i need to rethink all this

Comment: If you do that, make sure you redirect to the correct URL if someone tries to access `/profile/43/incorrect-username-for-uid-43/` (just like SO) so you don't get penalized for duplicate content. Also, personally I think `/profile/43-username/` looks better and is more logical.

Comment: thanks for this ideas. ill sleep on them and figure out the best way to do this. Also my real point was that i already have a link `website.com/john` with a certain rank and if ill redo it differently it will loose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more general than ZF specific question.

What you can do here to make the URL nice AND save your URL with high rankings is implemented in WordPress and called slugs. Slug is just the post title (just spaces replaced by hyphen and etc). But obviously there may be two posts with the same title (and, automatically, slug). So if the slug for the new post already exists it is appended by number '1' at the end. If it also exists, it is appended by '2' and repeats till it gets something unique. Obviously, you need to add a column in the table for the slug.

So in your case the first user with name John has the url `www.website.com/profile/John`. The next user with the name John has the url `www.website.com/profile/John1` and so on.